# display element difference between 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I wouldlike to show only element different between this 2 arrays :

```
a = [['test A', 'test B', 'test C', 'test D'], ['test E', 'test F', 'test G', 'test H'], ['test G']]
b = [['test A', 'test B'], ['test E', 'test G'], ['test I', 'test G']]
```

something like that :

```
out = [['test C', 'test D'], ['test F', 'test H'], ['test H']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out = [ list(set(x).symmetric_difference(y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Is that what you wanted?